# Personal loan to start the LLC now being paid back to investor / member of the LLC

Tags: united-states, income-tax, loans, limited-liability-company, personal-loan

I lent $85k to my own two partner LLC to purchase a property. I hold this as an interest bearing note against the property. I have been receiving a 1099-INT at the end of each year. Now, since the company is profitable I am beginning to repay that original loan. Where on my 1040 do I state that this is a repayment of a loan so that I don't have to pay taxes on the return of my own money?

Comment: **Do** you even mention it on your 1040?  I don't think so.  (You probably want to retain some evidence that it's a loan repayment in case the IRS asks...)